# DelphiTwain problem when scanning with 600dpi

Tags: image, delphi, twain

I have a problem with document scanning. I use DelphiTwain component over Delphi XE7, everything on Windows 10 x64. Scanner that I use is HP MFP M125nw.

When I scan with the smallest resolution, it works well, but when I scan with 600dpi, 4 of 10 tries failes this way, that component loses connection with driver (scanner continues scanning, but I'm getting incomplete picture - picture shows scanned object from the top, but later it's just black and contains nothing... sometime it scans 30% of the scanning area, sometime 70% sometime 10%).

Here is my code...

I was trying also native transfer mode, but the problem is the same - sometime it works, sometime it does not.

Does anyone know what could I do to get it working as expected each time I scan?

```
  Twain := TDelphiTwain.Create;

  if Twain.LoadLibrary then
  begin
    Twain.SourceManagerLoaded := TRUE;

    Twain.Source[src].Loaded := True;

    if Twain.Source[src].Loaded = True then
    begin
      Twain.Source[src].SetIXResolution(600);
      Twain.Source[src].SetIYResolution(600);
      Twain.Source[src].SetICapUnits(tuInches);
      Twain.Source[src].SetImagelayoutFrame(0, 0, (TicketWidth / 10) / 2.54, (TicketHeight / 10) / 2.54);
      Twain.Source[src].SetIPixelType(tbdRgb);
      Twain.Source[src].TransferMode := TTwainTransferMode(0);
      Twain.Source[src].SetupFileTransfer(tf + '~ticket.bmp', TTwainFormat.tfBMP);
      Twain.Source[src].EnableSource(False,False);

      While Twain.Source[src].Enabled do
      begin
        Application.ProcessMessages;
      end;
      Twain.UnloadLibrary;
      Twain.Free;
      tmr_OCR.Enabled := True;
    end else
      ShowMessage('Can''t contact scanner');
  end else
    ShowMessage('Twain is not installed.');
```

## ===============================
===========Edit================

I've got request to put all code here

There are five files:

- Project1.dpr
- uFrmMain.pas
- uFrmMain.dfm
- uFrmScan.pas
- uFrmScan.dfm

so...

Project1.dpr

```
program Project1;

uses
  Vcl.Forms,
  uFrmScan in 'uFrmScan.pas' {FrmScan},
  uFrmMain in 'uFrmMain.pas' {FrmMain};

{$R *.res}

begin
  Application.Initialize;
  Application.MainFormOnTaskbar := True;
  Application.CreateForm(TFrmMain, FrmMain);
  Application.CreateForm(TFrmScan, FrmScan);
  Application.Run;
end.
```

uFrmMain.pas

```
unit uFrmMain;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Vcl.StdCtrls, DelphiTwain, DelphiTwain_Vcl, Vcl.ExtCtrls;

type
  TFrmMain = class(TForm)
    btn_1: TButton;
    procedure btn_1Click(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
  end;

var
  FrmMain: TFrmMain;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

uses uFrmScan;

procedure TFrmMain.btn_1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  FrmScan := TFrmScan.Create(Self);
  FrmScan.ShowModal;
end;

end.
```

uFrmMain.dfm

```
object FrmMain: TFrmMain
  Left = 0
  Top = 0
  Caption = 'FrmMain'
  ClientHeight = 299
  ClientWidth = 424
  Color = clBtnFace
  Font.Charset = DEFAULT_CHARSET
  Font.Color = clWindowText
  Font.Height = -11
  Font.Name = 'Tahoma'
  Font.Style = []
  OldCreateOrder = False
  PixelsPerInch = 96
  TextHeight = 13
  object btn_1: TButton
    Left = 136
    Top = 120
    Width = 147
    Height = 25
    Caption = 'Open scan window'
    TabOrder = 0
    OnClick = btn_1Click
  end
end
```

uFrmScan.pas

```
unit uFrmScan;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Vcl.StdCtrls, DelphiTwain, DelphiTwain_Vcl, Vcl.ExtCtrls;

type
  TFrmScan = class(TForm)
    btn_1: TButton;
    pnl_1: TPanel;
    lbl_1: TLabel;
    lst_Sources: TListBox;
    img_1: TImage;
    btn_2: TButton;
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
    procedure btn_1Click(Sender: TObject);
    procedure btn_2Click(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    procedure Scan(dpi : Integer);
  end;

var
  FrmScan: TFrmScan;

const TicketWidth : Integer = 8;
      TicketHeight : Integer = 12;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TFrmScan.btn_1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Scan(96)
end;

procedure TFrmScan.btn_2Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Scan(600)
end;

procedure TFrmScan.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var Twain : TDelphiTwain;
    i : Integer;
begin
  Twain := TDelphiTwain.Create;

  if Twain.LoadLibrary then
  begin
    //Load source manager
    Twain.SourceManagerLoaded := TRUE;

    lst_Sources.Items.Clear;
    for I := 0 to Twain.SourceCount-1 do
      lst_Sources.Items.Add(Twain.Source[I].ProductName);

    if lst_Sources.Items.Count > 0 then
      lst_Sources.ItemIndex := 0;
  end else begin
    ShowMessage('Twain is not installed.');
  end;
  Twain.UnloadLibrary;
  Twain.Free;
end;

procedure TFrmScan.Scan(dpi: Integer);
var Twain : TDelphiTwain;
    src : Integer;
begin
  if FileExists('~ticket.bmp') then
    DeleteFile('~ticket.bmp');

  Twain := TDelphiTwain.Create;

  src := lst_Sources.ItemIndex;

  if Twain.LoadLibrary then
  begin
    Twain.SourceManagerLoaded := TRUE;

    Twain.Source[src].Loaded := True;

    if Twain.Source[src].Loaded = True then
    begin
      Twain.Source[src].SetIXResolution(dpi);
      Twain.Source[src].SetIYResolution(dpi);
      Twain.Source[src].SetICapUnits(tuInches);
      Twain.Source[src].SetImagelayoutFrame(0, 0, 3.15, 4.72);
      Twain.Source[src].SetIPixelType(tbdRgb);
      Twain.Source[src].TransferMode := TTwainTransferMode(0);
      Twain.Source[src].SetupFileTransfer('~ticket.bmp', TTwainFormat.tfBMP);
      Twain.Source[src].EnableSource(False,False);

      While Twain.Source[src].Enabled do
      begin
        Application.ProcessMessages;
      end;
      Twain.UnloadLibrary;
      Twain.Free;

      img_1.Picture.LoadFromFile('~ticket.bmp');
    end else
      ShowMessage('Can''t contact scanner');
  end else
    ShowMessage('Twain is not installed.');
end;

end.
```

uFrmScan.dfm

```
object FrmScan: TFrmScan
  Left = 0
  Top = 0
  Caption = 'FrmScan'
  ClientHeight = 299
  ClientWidth = 424
  Color = clBtnFace
  Font.Charset = DEFAULT_CHARSET
  Font.Color = clWindowText
  Font.Height = -11
  Font.Name = 'Tahoma'
  Font.Style = []
  OldCreateOrder = False
  OnCreate = FormCreate
  PixelsPerInch = 96
  TextHeight = 13
  object img_1: TImage
    Left = 210
    Top = 3
    Width = 208
    Height = 262
    Proportional = True
    Stretch = True
  end
  object btn_1: TButton
    Left = 210
    Top = 271
    Width = 95
    Height = 25
    Caption = 'Scan with 96dpi'
    TabOrder = 1
    OnClick = btn_1Click
  end
  object pnl_1: TPanel
    AlignWithMargins = True
    Left = 3
    Top = 3
    Width = 201
    Height = 293
    Align = alLeft
    BevelOuter = bvLowered
    Caption = 'pnl_1'
    TabOrder = 0
    object lbl_1: TLabel
      Left = 1
      Top = 1
      Width = 199
      Height = 13
      Align = alTop
      Caption = 'Source'
      ExplicitWidth = 33
    end
    object lst_Sources: TListBox
      Left = 1
      Top = 14
      Width = 199
      Height = 278
      Align = alClient
      ItemHeight = 13
      TabOrder = 0
    end
  end
  object btn_2: TButton
    Left = 311
    Top = 271
    Width = 105
    Height = 25
    Caption = 'Scan with 600 dpi'
    TabOrder = 2
    OnClick = btn_2Click
  end
end
```

[Here is a link to components website](http://www.kluug.net/delphitwain.php)

Comment: You should avoid the loop calling ProcessMessages and use the event OnTwainAcquire to do what you need. In other words, use the event driven paradigm.

Comment: Thanks @fpiette, but this does not solve the problem... That's what I started with and the story was exactly the same - maybe even worse - the scanning procedure got interrupted and OnTwainAcquire was never called.

Comment: You need to provide a [mre] that demonstrates the issue.

Comment: @KenWhite - sure... no problem... Here it is

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1bXbqUThK4lp9HQXDVNw78BckHGj-Nd-s/view?usp=sharing

I've created test project and I've made also video recording... You can see that the same code fails two times in row, then three times works well and then fails again... All without application restart.

Comment: Sorry, no. The relevant code needs to be here, in the question itself, in the form of a [mre], so that it is available to future site users. This is specifically required by the guidelines in the [help/on-topic]. We don't go off-site to get information required for your question.

Comment: Alright... here you go... I edited my post

Comment: I don't want to be that guy but I'm afraid I need to be. Go read accompanying documentation that comes with Delphi Twain library. As fpiette already hinted Delphi Twain library is designed to be used by even driven approach. Also had you read the documentation you would have learned that some functions like `SetImagelayoutFrame` have return value which could tel you if the function was successful or not like for instance if you are low on memory which based on your description of the issues you are encountering might be the most probable cause.

Comment: PS If you are having problems reading accompanying documentation (no content seen in chm reader on modern windows) like I did you could always convert this documentation into HTML file using online CHM to HTML converters like [Aconvert.com CHM to HTML](https://www.aconvert.com/ebook/chm-to-html/) as I did in order to be able to read the documentation.

Comment: I noticed that after scanning you are also performing OCR recognition of the scanned image. I recommend you also consider checking if your OCR recognition engine can work with other image formats besides BMP and change scanning image format to some other that supports at least some level of compression. Why? Scanning A4 sheet with 600 DPI resolution in full RGB color means that your scanned image size is about 100 MB in size for each page. So if you are working with multi-page documents you can quickly run out of memory when going to 600 DPI scanning resolution.

Comment: I read the documentary :) I choose ttmFile transferMode because in further steps I actually need a file on the drive. Saving the file to BMP or JPG is not relevant here... I'm scanning area 8x12 cm (~3x5 inch) which even as bitmat makes file of 15MB, which is nothing.

Comment: Regarding all the settings I make (SetIXResolution, SetImagelayoutFrame) and so on... they all give me back crSuccess in cases when procedure works well and in cases when it does it fails. I never got anything like crUnsupported, crBadOperation or crLowMemory.

Comment: Every time the procedure fails, the schema is the same... EnableSource is correctly executed, it returns True and procedure does into ----- While Twain.Source[src].Enabled do Application.ProcessMessages;. If all is fine, this loop continues until whole area is scanned and file is saved. In case when procedure fails, it simply quits this loop before physical scanner finished his work. In successful cases, OnSourceFileTransfer is called. In case if that quits the loop (procedure fails) this event is not called.

Comment: Regarding While Twain.Source[src].Enabled do .... According to documentary, EnableSource - The method starts the process of transferring the image from the source to the application...... The method also sets the Enabled property to TRUE to tell the application that the source is currently working..... After the user interface is closed or the image is transfered, the property will be re-set to FALSE ... .... So it looks that Twain.Source[src].Enabled is set to FALSE by component itself BEFORE scanning procedure finished.

Comment: Have you set up `OnTwainError` event handler? Does it fire in your cases? This event should report any error that might have happened anytime during the scanning process. As for `Twain.Source[src].Enabled` property it will be set to false in both scenarios whether the scanning process has succeeded or not.

Comment: Well... not before, but I did it now... It throws ErrorCode = TWRC_FAILURE, Additional = TWCC_BUMMER - Failed for unknown causes.

Comment: Based on the ErrorCode it appears that the error might be occurring in the Twain Driver for your scanner itself and not in your software. So first I would recommend you update your drivers. Especially if you are on windows 10. Recent updates for Windows 10 caused havoc in our company because most of our scanners stooped working or their TWAIN drivers simply began to crashing for no apparent reason. Also you might consider updating your Scanner firmware. We solved problems on most computers by updating drivers. On few we are still experiencing problems occasionally.